# Butterworth filter poles

Tags: infinite-impulse-response, z-transform, poles-zeros, butterworth

[image]

Hi,

I'm looking at this textbook question and trying to get a better idea of exactly what its asking.

For the processing to be real valued each pole would have to have a complex conjugate right?

So for the two points closest to the real axis, we would call $e^{j\omega_0} $ & $e^{-j\omega_0}$, then the next two at 45 degree angles $e^{j\omega_1} $ & $e^{-j\omega_1}$ and the two most vertical points $e^{j\omega_2} $ & $e^{-j\omega_2}$

And these would be our 6 poles.

But then how does this relate to higher order filters being created with minimal algebra?

Comment: What happens if you add poles right in the middle of each pair?

Answer (score 2):

> But then how does this relate to higher order filters being created with minimal algebra?

The key phrase -- which should be in the text *someplace* -- is that the poles of a Butterworth filter are evenly spaced, and hence very predictable.

If the book has already gone into constructing the Butterworth filter transfer function, go back and study up.  If this is a book about realizing filters and you're just expected to **know** how to construct a Butterworth, go study up.  Sometimes authors like to do some foreshadowing in their questions, and they'll cover the topic in detail later -- if so, feel free to look ahead.

At any rate, the Butterworth poles are located* at

$$s = \exp \left [j \frac{\pi}{2} \left(1 + \frac{1 + 2k}{n}\right) \right]\ \forall\ k \in [0, n),$$
so you can work that out for higher (or lower) orders.

* from *Passive and Active Network Analysis and Synthesis*, Aram Budak, Houghton Mifflin, 1974.  Oldy, yes, but definitely a goody.

Comment: Wow. Budak is a blast from the past.  That's the text I used in undergrad. :-)

Comment: It was the text for the active filters class I took while getting my Master's degree.  It was the only super-easy class that I've taken that I've _also_ used material from throughout my career.

Comment: I mean -- what's changed that requires a revision?  Resistors and caps are smaller, and GBW bandwidths are bigger, but the basics are the same.

Comment: Certainly! I wasn't dissing it, just amazed that someone else knows the book. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> For the processing to be real valued each pole would have to have a complex conjugate right?

Correct

> And these would be our 6 poles.

Correct

> But then how does this relate to higher order filters being created with minimal algebra?

That depends a bit on your definition of "minimal algebras". The standard way of doing this, is to split this into 3 cascaded section, each of which has one complex conjugate pole pair and dual zero at infinity (in the s-plane) or a dual zero at $z = -1$ (in the z-plane).